# The code-generation of my .resx resource stop working

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, resources, code-generation, resx

Normally when we add new rows to a .resx file, say Resources.resx, in the IDE's resource editor, the code-behind file, say Resources.Designer.cs, will be automatically updated - adding new properties for the new rows.

But in my situation, that automation has stopped working. Have you met the same problem? If you do, please help me to get .resx back to work :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what I found that works:

1. Delete the `Resources.Designer.cs` file
2. In Solution Explorer, exclude the `Resources.resx`
3. Then, show all files, re-include the `Resources.resx`.
   The `Resources.Designer.cs` file should be recreated then.
4. Reset the 'Access Modifier' to be 'Public' (see details [here](http://namgivu.wordpress.com/2010/12/09/how-to-get-the-code-generation-of-resx-resource-file-back-to-work/))
5. Right click `Resources.resx` in Solution Explorer and click `Run custom tool`

Hope this would be helpful to you!

Comment: This worked for me, thanks :) however after I completed it I realized my Access Modifier was previously already set to "No code generation". Not sure why, but I wonder if just changing that back to public would also force the re-generation of the designer.cs files?

Answer (score 1):

A very similar problem arises with aspx/ascx files.  This involved deleting the designer and then clicking "convert to web application" to force code gen of the designer again.  Don't know if a similar facility exists for the resx.

Comment: Thank you brumScouse! Your suggestion helps me find the answer!